# Running Spark on a cluster of machines of a Super Computer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cluster-computing

I want to run my Spark code on a cluster of machines instead of standalone mode, 
there is 1 Gig of text on local machine,

i have a super computer with 30 nodes and every node has 32 cores cpu and 64G Ram.

this is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
object Pre5 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    case class Bigram(first: String, second: String,third: String) {
      def mkReplacement(s: String) = s.replaceAll(first + " " + second + " " + third, first + "-" + second + "-" + third)
    }

    def stringToBigrams(s: String) = {
      val sentences = s.split("\\.")
      sentences.flatMap { sent =>
        val words = sent.split("\\s+").filter(_ != "")
        if (words.length >= 3)
          words.sliding(3).map(a => Bigram(a(0), a(1), a(2)))
        else
          Iterator[Bigram]()
      }
    }

    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local")
      .setAppName("LDA")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val data = sc.textFile("data/input"")

      val replaced1 = data.zipWithIndex()
        .map { case (line, i) => i.toString + "," + line}
      val bigrams = replaced1.flatMap(stringToBigrams(_)).collect()

      //use reduceByKey rather than groupBy for Spark
      val bigramCounts = bigrams.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
      var threshold = 70
      val topBigrams = bigramCounts.filter(_._2 >= threshold).map(_._1)
      val replaced = replaced1.map(r => topBigrams1.foldLeft(r)((r, b) =>    b.mkReplacement(r)))
      replaced.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("data/Pre5")

    }
  }
}
```

i want to specify number of cores and specify amount of RAM for every nodes, for example:

> using 10 nodes with  10 cores and 10G RAM

How can i run this code according above specified features?

Answer (score 0):

Spark supports Mesos and YARN as cluster manager. I use YARN and it can be controlled with following parameters (Mesos also has similar parameters) when submitting spark job.

```
spark-submit ...
--num-executors 10 \
--executor-memory 10g \
--executor-cores 10 \
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

Basically, you need to use spark-submit. From your code, remove `setMaster("local")` and `set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")` from SparkConf. They'll be set by the `spark-submit` parameters.

If you don't know Mesos or YARN availabilty, please ask supercomputer admin.

Comment: Is it possible to use spark in a cluster mode without YARN?

Comment: Yes, try to use Mesos. Spark supports Mesos and YARN as cluster manager.

Comment: how ? i know there is Mesos cluster manager, but i don't know how to implement these on super computer because super computer admin doesn't know about spark.

Comment: Here is how to run spark on Mesos. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html Does the admin know Mesos or YARN?

Comment: no he doesn't know any thing about spark, i have a question : should i copy spark on all nodes?

Comment: I forgot that there is another mode: spark standalone mode. Yes, you need to copy spark to all nodes. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html